# Web API 2 returning empty response body

Tags: c#, angular

I have an ApiController that is returning a List of Strings from an async call.
If I hit the backend with Postman I can see a correct response body with the list of strings, but when I call it from my Angular App I see an empty response body in the network tab of the browser.

### Web API Action

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("overview/codes")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCodes()
{
   try
   {
       var codes = await _service.GetCodesAsync();
       return Ok(codes);
   }
   catch (ArgumentNullException)
   {
       return NotFound();
   }
}
```

### c# Service method

```
public async Task<IList<string>> GetCodesAsync()
{
   using (var context = await _dataContextFactory.Create())
   {
       return await context.Tracking.Select(tracking => tracking.Code).ToListAsync();
   }
}
```

### Angular Code

This is the method in the service and the URL is correct cause I can see that the request is hitting the backend.

```
getCodes(): Observable<String[]> {
   return this.http.get<String[]>("THE_URL");
}
```

And the part of the code calling the service:

```
codes : String[];

ngOnInit() {
   this.getCodes();
}

getCodes(): void {
   this.service.getCodes().subscribe(codes => this.codes = codes);
}
```

Comment: Check the network tab in your browser developer tools to make sure the request is getting called, you can inspect the response there also. What is subscribing to the observable to make it call the endpoint ? Do you have an Async | pipe in your template?

Comment: What's the response status code? Anything in you server's log?

Comment: When I check the network tab in the browser's dev tools I can see a 200 code but the response body is empty. I set a breakpoint in the C# code and I can see that the method in the controller is hit and it is sending a response back as I can see in the browser as well.

Comment: which version of `angular` are u using?

Comment: I'm using angular 6

Comment: `I see an empty response body` <= Where specifically are you seeing an empty response body?

Comment: Your c# and angular code look fine to me.

Comment: When I check the network tab in the developer tools. I can see the request and in the response I receive a 200 status but the response body is empty and when I hit the endpoint with Postman I can see the response body and it is correct.

Comment: Just to double check: Did you verify that the called URLs are identical between PostMan and the Browser (looking in the network traffic tab)?

Comment: Yes, actually I copied it manually and hardcoded it in the service just in case.

Comment: Is there anything else that might alter the result? Authenticated request via cookie or session state etc? Because if I were to take the above code and build an [mcve] I know for a fact it would work which means there is something else (*that we can't see as we dont' have access to your computer*) going on.

Comment: One more test. As this is a HttpGet end point, copy the URL directly into the browsers address bar (use a new tab if you want to). What comes back there?

Comment: Uhmm, I'm thinking it may be related to authentication then. I'm surprised as it is working when called from Postman and I can see the request hitting the endpoint and sending a response but the auth part may be blocking it. I'm new to C# so trying to understand how things work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.

The problem was with CORS and the authentication. Missing some config for that hence I could hit the endpoint but as my angular App wasn't registered it wouldn't send it the response body.